# 80s movie about robots, like first Transformers or Robotix

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Please help identify an old movie I watched as a kid on VHS.

The story is about two nations of robots fighting each other in some planet. I'm not sure if there is any humans in this story, robots only.

It was very similar to Transformers. Way of drawing and artistic impression was similar to Robotix (it could have similar producer, studio or artistic inspiration). When I found Robotix, at first look I thought that was Robotix, but, as I remember, story was better and way of drawing robots was better.

I saw this movie on VHS, that could by Japanese, French, Italy or English production.

Comment: Was it live show or animated?

Comment: It was animated.

Comment: The other big one like that was Voltron.

Comment: Voltron have humans in the stroy.

Comment: I`m sure there was no humans at all and story is placed in some distant planet

Comment: I spend last hour to try find that movie in "top 100 mecha-anime" or "top 80s movies" and i cant :/ i think that was a very small production or is ranked very bad ;)

Comment: Are there any more movies with a similar premise -- in addition to _Transformers_ and _Robotix_ -- that you can confirm **aren't** the one you're looking for? If so, please edit your question to list them, so they can be eliminated from the search.

Comment: There was a cartoon series on tv called Go-bots, but I dont think it was ever a movie.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 there was a “Go-Bots: The Movie” I believe.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 : "GoBots: Battle of the Rock Lords" was the movie.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoBots:_Battle_of_the_Rock_Lords

Comment: could it be one of the episodes of the transformers series, there were lots of cybertron episodes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Transformers_episodes